# Angular svg image preview

Tags: angular, svg

I trying to do image preview with angular using fileReader and creating data url, but the image never loads the svg, but jpg and etc. works.

example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqlsb5)

I also tryed to take it as plain text and add it as innerHtml to div which works ,but the image have width: 100mm and height: 100mm, which means the image doens't scale to its container. I tryed to change this in css but it didn't work either...

example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frwrbe)

I also added some svg img to src DIR for testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because of security. The difference between `svg` and `jpg/png` is in the structure since `svg` uses `xml` and the `jpg/png` are bitmaps.  So when they are translated to `base64` `svg` is untrusted and `jpg/png` is trusted.

As [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) says

> For example, when binding a URL in an <a [href]="someValue">
> hyperlink, someValue will be sanitized so that an attacker cannot
> inject e.g. a javascript: URL that would execute code on the website.

> WARNING: calling this method with untrusted user data exposes your
> application to XSS security risks!

### More simple way

You can just add `bypassSecurityTrustUrl()` to your method

So it will look like this

```
  selectedImageChanged(event) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = async e => {
      const value = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(fileReader.result as string);
      this.previewFileUrl = value;
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
```

### More complex way

The second possible way is to create a pipe which will do the same.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'unSafe'
})
export class UnSafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
 
 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }
}
```

The use of this pipe is very simple in your code it would look like this.

```
<img [src]="previewFileUrl | unSafe: 'url'" alt=alt/>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dc4qbg)

**Don't forget to put the UnSafePipe into module dependencies.**

Comment: You should rather name the pipe unsafe, as what you are literally doing is bypassing the security measures of Angular and the name gives the false impression that it's safe to use this pipe rather than potentially opening up security issues.

Comment: @Hendrik Yes, I will also add warning for potential XSS attacks as it is in Angular documentation. Since this is a bit old answer I wasn't aware of this. Thank you!